# Inserting parentheses to produce different values

Tags: notation

> Without grouping symbols, the expression
>   $$\verb/2 ⋅ 3 ^ 3 + 4/$$  
>   has a value of $58$. Insert grouping symbols in the expression $\verb/2 ⋅ 3 ^ 3 + 4/$ to produce the indicated values.
>
> A. $62$
>   B. $220$
>   C. $4{,}374$
>   D. $279{,}936$

I have solved for A and B.

A.  $2\cdot ( 3^3 + 4 ) = 62$

B.  $(2\cdot 3)^3 + 4 = 220$

C and D just seem impossible to conjure.

Comment: I wonder what $6^7$ is,

Comment: probably more than $2\cdot 3^7$

Comment: @DavidMitra Okay but where did you place grouping symbols to get that?

Comment: Actually, the formula should be typeset linearly, $2\cdot3\ 3+4$.

Comment: @marisol  this is more of a "game" questions than serious math. Maybe it is clearer if I don't use the mathjax "2 x 3 ^ 3 + 4" ,now insert parentheses

Comment: @Marisol Does my answer help?

Comment: Hmm... Is $(2\cdot3)^{(3}+4)$ legal? I would agree with you now.

Comment: @BetterWorld yes, the result is correct but how is inserting paranthesis between 3 and ^3 and after +4  legit?

Comment: @Marisol Sorry,  but I couldn't understand your query. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Your  original question (if I remember correctly) was: $$$$2.3^3+4,$$$$ right? Here, you can quite easily rewrite the above expression as $$$$2.3^(3+4)$$$$The rest follows.

Comment: @BetterWorld What i meant was, is it even possible to separate a base from its exponent by using grouping symbols ( parenthesis) ? Because that's the only way that you could get 279,936.

Comment: again @marisol this problem is meant as a joke or if you will a practice in out of the box thinking. If you are interested in a more legit problem, try e) 126

Comment: @Bort yes, it does seem like a joke but it can't be because it's in my sister's algebra book... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider the following: $$2\times 3^{(3+4)}$$$$(2\times 3)^{(3+4)}$$